# Xamarin Forms - how to get app to resume to same view onResume

Tags: xamarin, splash-screen, main-activity

Since I've implemented a splash activity in my XF app I cannot get the view to persist an app minimize/resume. It worked fine with just one activity. Currently, as per Microsoft's documentation, I have them as mainlauncher- true, nohistory - true in splash activity, false in the other. Anyone experience anything similar?
this is only an issue on android.

Running cross-platform 3.1

Comment: Review `logcat` to determine if the OS is killing off your app, typically this is due to memory pressure...

Comment: checked, no crash, the app itself works fine on ios and resumes perfectly so it's to do with having main/splash activity implemented. can you please assist with a working example based on your experience? @SushiHangover

Comment: It would not be reported as a crash, the OS would kill the process and that would be reported in logcat

Comment: The same here, I'm starting to dig into it. Do you have any solution?